# How to Force Autoredirect http://example.com to https://example.com through .htacess file

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, https

I have a Domain where a Wildcard SSL is Installed. We have made modifications in the Sub Domains and its autoredrecting from HTTP to HTTPS for Sub Domains.

But for the main domain, since its http://example.com, I am unable to redirect it to https://example.com [to be same without a www].

All examples that I am getting from web and research are for www to non-www or non-www to www.

My Requirement is HTTPS for non-www to non-www.

The Code that works for my Sub Domains is not working for the Non-WWW.

Working Code on Subdomains is as shown below :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I Expect http://example.com to Force Autoredicrection to https://example.com

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Hope it works for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi Lalit, Tried this but didnt work for me. My Server is on Godaddy Linux Hosting. If this info helps.

Comment: @GauravMody Please try `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^coolexample\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.coolexample\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

from config.php and enable or set hooks to true:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Then create a new file named hooks.php inside the config folder and add the following :

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
    'filename' => 'ssl.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Create a new directory named hooks inside the application folder (i.e. application/hooks) and then create a new file named ssl.php inside
Add the following code in the ssl.php file:

```
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
        // redirecting to ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } else {
        // redirecting with no ssl.
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```